Drawing an "atlas" map
I'm working on a math paper and I'm aiming to include an infographic that illustrates the decomposition of a particular space into five sub-areas. My idea is to represent the space as a circle, with the five areas resembling countries forming a partition within the circle.
I've experimented with pie charts, but they don't quite capture the 'natural borders' I envision, as they use straight lines for separation. Could you point me towards a relevant manual or provide examples that align more closely with what I'm trying to achieve?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... And perhaps you can add an image showing what you want to get ...

Maybe you could play around with random steps.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
    randomcircle/.style={
        circle, draw, line width=2pt, 
        minimum height=#1, rounded corners,
        decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=3mm, amplitude=3pt}
    },
    randomline/.style={
        line width=2pt, rounded corners,
        decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=4mm, amplitude=3pt}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{71828}

\node[randomcircle=5cm](A){};
\node[randomcircle=1.5cm](B) at ([shift={(-.5,-.7)}]A){};
\draw[randomline] (B)--(A.-23)(B)--(A.60)(B)--(A.120)(B)--(A.240);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


It turned out to be exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.


Just drawing some interior shapes as closed paths then drawing unclosed paths between a control point in each of the shapes.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=5cm];
  \draw plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(0,0) (1,0) (2,1) (1,2)};
  \draw plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(-1,-1) (-2,0) (-1.5,.5) (-2,1) (-1,2)};
  \draw plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(1.5,-1)  (2.5,-2) (2,-3) (0,-4) (1,-1)};

  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(0,0) (-.3,1) (-1,2)};
  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(-1,-1) (-2,-2) (-4,1) (-5,0)};
  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(2,1) (4,-1.5) (2.5,-2)};
  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(0,-4) (-1,-4.5) (0,-5)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

